# Animating circles getting clipped using D3.js with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js

I am trying to animate some SVG circles across the entire `body` element of a webpage, but they seem to be getting clipped when they reach this line, `<%= yield %>` in the `application.html.erb` of the RoR app.

The *application.html.erb* looks like the following,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>KegCop</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
  <%= render 'layouts/ie_shim' %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
  <div id="container-fluid">

    <%= render 'layouts/bubbles' %>

    <%= yield %>

    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

  </div>
<%= render 'layouts/google_analytics' %>
<%= render 'layouts/beer_background' %>
<%= audio_tag("/audios/bottle-open.ogg", autoplay: true, controls: false) %>


</body>
</html>
```

And the D3.js script that animates the bubbles, *_bubbles.html.erb*

```
w = window.innerWidth,
h = window.innerHeight;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(d3.range(70).map(function(datum,interval) {
          return {
            x: interval*20,
            y: 0,
            dx: 5,
            dy: -3 * (Math.random()+1),
            mu: Math.random()*2
          };
        }))
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .attr("fill","blue")
        .attr("opacity",".5");

    var text = svg.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", 20)
        .attr("y", 20);

    var start = Date.now(),
        frames = 0;

    d3.timer(function() 
    {

      // Update the FPS meter.
      var now = Date.now(), duration = now - start;
      text.text(~~(++frames * 1000 / duration));
      if (duration >= 1000) frames = 0, start = now;

      // Update the circle positions.
      circle
          .attr("cx", function(d) { d.x += Math.random()*3*Math.sin(Math.random()*3*d.x + Math.random()*10); if (d.x > w) d.x -= w; else if (d.x < 0) d.x += w; return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { d.y += d.dy ; if (d.y > h) d.y -= h; else if (d.y < 0) d.y += h; return d.y; })
          .attr("r",function(d)
          {
            return (d.y < 100) ? d3.select(this).attr("r") : d.mu*500/d.y;
          });
    });
```

**Update:**

Below is what I would expect to see, but it is clipping off at the bottom of the form elements on the webpage I am working with.

http://jsfiddle.net/ipatch/4C8c8/8/

Comment: It sounds like your canvas simply isn't big enough if you're seeing clipping.

Comment: I am putting a jsfiddle together to describe what is going on, please give me a moment.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff fiddle added.

Comment: You can see what I am talking about if you visit kegcop.chrisrjones.com

Comment: Wait, so you have a working version?

Comment: Well I would like the bubbles to work like they do in the jsfiddle link posted above not how their getting clipped at this current moment.

Comment: I don't mean to be flippant, but surely you can figure out what's different in the two versions yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing `<div id="container-fluid">` to `<div class="wrapper">` and changing the `wrapper` CSS style to `position: absolute` and now the "bubbles" / SVG circles are animating across the entire `<body>` element of the page.

The key was setting the wrapper class to a position of absolute.